# Having problems with set and get methods in java

Tags: java

What's wrong with my program? Webcat says I have a problem with every set and get method in my program, but I don't know what's the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5BVU.png)

Comment: looks ok to me, idk what webcat is but maybe it's broke

Comment: What is the specific error that webcat reports? I don't see anything obviously incorrect from that picture.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to understand what we expect from our users and their posts.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: @robotlos Probably right, syntax highlighting and highlighting of the lines is off too.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [MCVE].

Comment: @BooRadley  It says nothing but highlighted those lines. That's what confused me.

Comment: I don't actually know what webcat is either, but as @robotlos suggested you probably need to clean/rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfectly okay,
maybe you're trying to instantiate the abstract class when you need to make a concrete class extending the abstract class

Comment: looks like you are right. Clay Geng is using an abstract class. Within abstract classes, you just define the method, not implement it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use your abstract class as a "normal" class, since you cannot instantiate an object from an abstract class.

Another option is that you create a second class like this:

```
public class newclass extends SoftballPlayer{
}
```

Then everything should be ok.

EDIT: Corrected an error within my first answer.

Comment: You can implement as many methods as you want in abstract classes.

Comment: Ok, then this was wrong in my mind (I will edit my answer). But he will not be able to instantiate from this abstract class, maybe that will be the problem...